Is the sum of measurable functions taking values in $\mathbb{R}^n$ again measurable?
Let $(X, \mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and let $f,g: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be two measurable functions. Is it then true that also their sum is measurable? All books I could get hold of only show the result for real-valued functions but not in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I would be happy about either an answer of my question or a reference to a book that shows the result (if it is true).

Yes, it's true. Try to prove the following proposition: a vector valued function $f=(f_1, \dots, f_n):X\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is measurable if and only if $f_i$ is measurable for each $i$. Here $f_i$ denotes the composition $\pi_i\circ f$ of $f$ with the $i$-th coordinate projection.
Then $f+g$ is defined to be the function $(f_1+g_1, \dots, f_n+g_n)$, so if you agree that the $f_i+g_i$ are measurable, then the proposition implies your result.
